# What is GLOB short for in Unix/Linux/Java world?

Tags: java, regex, linux, unix, idioms

The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) page explains what GLOB means.

However, it still doesn't say what GLOB is short for.

Any explanations?

Comment: From that very page: ‘*Its name is an abbreviation for "global command".*’

Comment: Tip: when you're looking for etymology on wikipedia page search for " name " (with spaces).

Answer (score 1):

As stated on the linked wiki page:

> Its name is an abbreviation for "global command".